# Using Azure WAF for my server(not in Azure)

Tags: azure, devops, azure-virtual-network, web-application-firewall, azure-waf

I have a server at my home with static IP and website in IIS, which available from internet. I wanted to protect it by Azure Web Application Firewall, but it works only in Azure Virtual Network.

Can I add my server to Azure Virtual Network?
Is it possible to protect my server which is not placed in cloud by WAF?

*I know, that I can use other services and apps, but I'm interested in only this setup*

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according with your case scenario and considering application Gateway backend pools can contain:

- NICs
- Virtual machine scale sets
- Public IP addresses
- Internal IP addresses
- FQDN
- Multitenant backends (such as App Service)

as per [Application gateway components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-components#backend-pools), you should be able to use your public IP address if the "On Prem" host is exposed to Internet.
If the "On Prem" host is not exposed to Internet, you should use a VPN or Expressroute allowing traffic from "on Prem" to the VNET.